# Using multithreading to capture image of UIView

Tags: iphone, multithreading, ios5, uiview, grand-central-dispatch

I am using Grand Central Dispatch to queue a task to capture a `UIView` as an image. Everything is working fine with this except that the image capturing running on a queue is taking quite a long time.

Is there any way to speed this up or improve my technique. Here is the code to capture and scale the image, which is then set to a `UIImageView`'s image for displaying.

```
(void)captureScrollViewImageForLayoverView
{
    // capture big map image
    CGSize size = mainView.bounds.size;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    [[mainView layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // scale map
    size = myLocationOverlay.bounds.size;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    [newImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,size.width,size.height)];
    UIImage *scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    myLocationOverlay.imageMap.image = scaledImage;
}
```

And Here is the code that is queueing the task.

```
...
mapImageDrawQueue = dispatch_queue_create("mapImage.drawQueue", NULL);

(void)captureScrollViewImageForLayoverViewWrapper {
    // multithreaded approach to draw map
    dispatch_async(mapImageDrawQueue, ^{ [self captureScrollViewImageForLayoverView]; });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to load images at queue in my app with same issue you mentioned. I checked official programming guide, remembered it told that it can't guarantee the queue run immediately after you call it. So I used NSThread do the job, and it's working well:

```
NSThread* myThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                        selector:@selector(captureScrollViewImageForLayoverView)
                                        object:nil];
[myThread start];
```

Remember add these lines to the function captureScrollViewImageForLayoverView:

At top : `NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];`
At end : `[pool release];`

Check this doc to know more - [Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html)
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will definitely do this and let you know how it works.

Comment: Hey, I finally have gotten around to trying this. So I am using ARC so it is telling me I can't declare an NSAutoreleasePool. Is there something else that needs to be done instead or can I just omit these lines?

Comment: Just omit it, ARC will do the job.